# How to put multiple annotations on the same line in a bokeh chart?

Tags: bokeh, multiline

So I'm making some bokeh charts and I want to add some text outside the plot area. Say I want to put one annotation above the top right corner and another above the top left corner. The issue I'm having is that bokeh is stacking these two annotations vertically, but I'd like them to be on the same line horizontally. Is there any way to do this?

Code:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import Legend

plot = figure(**plot_params)    
date_label = Legend(items=[('label1', [])], location='center_left', border_line_color=None, margin=0)
plot.add_layout(date_label, 'above')

resource_label = Legend(items=[('label2', [])], location='center_right', border_line_color=None, margin=0)
plot.add_layout(resource_label, 'above')
```

[output example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKp7C.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `min_border` property to expand plot dimensions and `Label` with `render_mode=css` to add the annotations in arbitrary places by playing around with `x` and `y` set to `screen` units.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook, show
from bokeh.models import Label

output_notebook()

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)

p.circle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 2, 4, 5], size=20, color="navy", alpha=0.5)
p.border_fill_color = "whitesmoke"
p.min_border = 50

top_left_label = Label(
    x=-35, y=320, x_units='screen', y_units='screen',
    text='Top Left Label', render_mode='css', background_fill_color='white')

bottom_right_label = Label(
    x=200, y=-45, x_units='screen', y_units='screen',
    text='Bottom Right Label', render_mode='css', background_fill_color='white')

p.add_layout(top_left_label)
p.add_layout(bottom_right_label)

show(p)
```

[image]

Note from the docs:

> The CSS labels won’t be present in the output using the “save” tool.

Comment: In my case the plot height and width aren't fixed - I'm using `sizing_mode='scale_both'` - so I can't specify explicit pixel amounts.

Comment: In that case, probably just easier to add annotations as part of your HTML markup and fix the layout with CSS. Or, if you really want to keep it strictly pure Bokeh, try column [layout](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/layout.html#column-layout).